how to add Interval time in snowflake using a parameter
We have a use case where user will provide starttime, endtime, and Interval as parameters. and we need to pass these parameters to view logic where we have business logic, But the Interval function is not accepting any parameters. Please help how to pass parameter to add interval. below is a simple example.
set v_StartTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-01 00:00:00');

set v_EndTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-02 00:00:00');

set v_Interval = '1 HOUR';

Below Statement works in snowflake:
SELECT $v_StartTime, $v_StartTime + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' , $v_EndTime;

Below Statement is not working while using $v_Interval as parameter:
SELECT $v_StartTime, ($v_StartTime + INTERVAL $v_Interval ) , $v_EndTime;


You can use seperate parameters for interval amount and type and feed that to dateadd
set v_StartTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-01 00:00:00');
set v_EndTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-02 00:00:00');
set v_Interval = 1;
set v_IntervalType = 'hour';

select $v_StartTime, dateadd($v_IntervalType, $v_Interval, $v_StartTime), $v_EndTime;


You are aware that you cannot run queries like this, correct?
This will produce errors in both Snowsight and SnowSQL.

Variables in Snowflake are quite unclear to a lot of people, hence I was asking if you were aware that a variable, in this context, cannot be called within a function the way you did it. Now your response here is edited, and now it works. If you run the query as it was before your edit you'll see what I mean.

If OP would have figured it out on their own, this question would not be here. Your response was incorrect, now it is not. Blame me all you want, but you not testing your code before you post it was the issue here and nothing else.

@Kathmandude  Thank You! Your solution worked for me , Perfect!!

You're technically building a query here. Instead of this approach, opt to create a dynamic query and then used EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on the query that I've just built as a string.
As the explained use case is not very descriptive I cannot imagine what you want to do with this right now so I have to do some guessing. But you can create both an UDF and an SP to do this for you with these values as input parameters.
The support for variables are different depending on what you're trying to do. Stored Procedures, Queries, Cursors, Loops and UDFs - so what you need to do here fully depend on your use case. This script will work using both SnowSQL and Snowsight.
Here is a sample query using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with an Dynamic Query. Do also note that you can use USING in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for bind variables:
-- Define variables
set v_StartTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-01 00:00:00');
set v_EndTime = to_timestamp_ntz('2024-04-02 00:00:00');
set v_Interval = '1 HOUR';

-- Construct the SQL statement dynamically
set v_SQL = '
    SELECT
        $v_StartTime AS StartTime,
        ($v_StartTime + INTERVAL ''' || $v_Interval || ''') AS IntervalTime,
        $v_EndTime AS EndTime
    ';

-- Execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $v_SQL;

